# JavaScript Form Validation one field at a time

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I need to write a script that does JavaScript validation but i need it to complete one field at a time. For example:

I have four fields; First Name, Last Name, Email, Age

If a user clicks the submit field and everything is blank it should only focus on the first field in the form (First Name) it would then throw an error message, focus that box, and turn the field red with a red border.

If they fill the First field it would then follow the steps for the second one (last name).

The only other curve ball is that the age field needs to only allow numbers and they must be between 0-80.

The current script i have is highlighting the forms correctly but it highlights all fields and focuses the last one. Age is also the only field throwing an error. Heres my script:

```
"use strict";

var deptList = ["SDEV","DBMS","INFM","CSCI","SVAD","NETI","ITSP","CSIA"];
var list = document.getElementById("progList");
var formValidity = true;
var errMsgDiv = document.getElementById("errorMsg");
function createCheck() {
    deptList.sort();
    for (var i = 0; i <= 7; i++) {
        (function(i) {
        var boxText = deptList[i];
        var deptEntry = document.createElement ("label");
        deptEntry.innerHTML = "<input type=checkbox name=programs[] value=" + i + " />" + boxText;
        list.appendChild (deptEntry);
        console.log("deptEntry");
  })(i);
 }
}
function validateInput(evt) {
  if (evt.preventDefault) {
    evt.preventDefault(); // prevent form from submitting
  } else {
    evt.returnValue = false; // prevent form from submitting in IE8
  }
  formValidity = true; // reset value for revalidation
  checkBlank();
  validateNumbers(); // additional
  if (formValidity === true) {
    document.getElementsByTagName("form")[0].submit();
  }
}
function createEventListeners() {
  var form = document.getElementsByTagName("form")[0];
   if (form.addEventListener) {
    form.addEventListener("submit", validateInput, false);
  } else if (form.attachEvent) {
    form.attachEvent("onsubmit", validateInput);
}
}
function checkBlank() {
  var chkBlnkVal = true;
  var fName = document.forms[0].fname;
  var lName = document.forms[0].lname;
  var email = document.forms[0].email;
  console.log("Entering checkBlank " + "form validity: " + formValidity +" check blank validity: " + chkBlnkVal);
 try { 
  if (fName.value === ''){
    fName.style.background = "rgb(255,233,233)";
    fName.style.borderColor = "red";
    chkBlnkVal = false;
    fName.focus();
  } else {
    fName.style.background = "white";
    fName.style.borderColor = "white";
  }
 if (chkBlnkVal === false) {
    throw "Please complete all fields.";
    }
    errMsgDiv.style.display = "none";
    errMsgDiv.innerHTML = "";
  }
 catch(msg) {
 errMsgDiv.style.display = "block";
 errMsgDiv.innerHTML = msg;
 formValidity = false;
 }
  try { 
  if (lName.value === ''){
    lName.style.background = "rgb(255,233,233)";
    lName.style.borderColor = "red";
    chkBlnkVal = false;
    lName.focus();
  } else {
    lName.style.background = "white";
    lName.style.borderColor = "white";
  }
 if (chkBlnkVal === false) {
    throw "Please complete all fields.";
    }
    errMsgDiv.style.display = "none";
    errMsgDiv.innerHTML = "";
  }
 catch(msg) {
 errMsgDiv.style.display = "block";
 errMsgDiv.innerHTML = msg;
 formValidity = false;
 }
 try { 
  if (email.value === ''){
    email.style.background = "rgb(255,233,233)";
    email.style.borderColor = "red";
    chkBlnkVal = false;
    email.focus();
  } else {
    email.style.background = "white";
    email.style.borderColor = "white";
  }
 if (chkBlnkVal === false) {
    throw "Please complete all fields.";
    }
    errMsgDiv.style.display = "none";
    errMsgDiv.innerHTML = "";
  }
 catch(msg) {
 errMsgDiv.style.display = "block";
 errMsgDiv.innerHTML = msg;
 formValidity = false;
 }
 console.log("Leaving checkBlank " + "form validity: " + formValidity +" check blank validity: " + chkBlnkVal +" First Name: " + fName.value);
}

function validateNumbers() {
  var numbersValidity = true;
  var age = document.forms[0].age;
  try {
  if (isNaN(age.value) || (age.value
      === "") || (age.value <= -1) || (age.value >= 81)) {
    age.style.background = "rgb(255,233,233)";
    age.style.borderColor = "red";
    numbersValidity = false;
    age.focus();
  } else {
    age.style.background = "white";
    age.style.borderColor = "white";
  }
  if (numbersValidity === false) {
    throw "Please enter valid number for age.";
    }
    errMsgDiv.style.display = "none";
    errMsgDiv.innerHTML = "";
  }
 catch(msg) {
 errMsgDiv.style.display = "block";
 errMsgDiv.innerHTML = msg;
 formValidity = false;
 }
 console.log("Leaving validateNumbers " + "form validity: " + formValidity +" numbers validity: " + numbersValidity +" age: " + age.value);
}
function init(){
    createEventListeners();
    createCheck();
}

if (window.addEventListener) {
   console.log("> Adding TC39 Event Listener...");
   window.addEventListener ("load", init, false);
}
else if (window.attachEvent) {
   console.log("> Adding MS Event Listener...");
   window.attachEvent ("onload", init);
}
```

This is the HTML that includes the form:

```
<form action="exam01.php" method="post" novalidate=novalidate>
<h2>School of Information Technology Membership Form</h2>
<p id="errorMsg"></p>
<fieldset id="left">
 <legend>Contact Info</legend>
 <p><span class="grid3">Name</span>
    <span class="grid1"><input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="First Name" size="15" maxlength="25" autofocus /></span>
    <span class="grid1"><input type="text" name="lname" placeholder="Last Name" size="15" maxlength="25" /></span>
 </p>
 <p><span class="grid3">eMail</span>
    <span class="grid2"><input type="email" name="email" placeholder="user@domain.com" size="35" /></span>
 </p>
 <p><span class="grid3">Age</span>
    <span class="grid2"><input type="number" name="age"  /></span>
 </p> 
</fieldset>
<fieldset id="right">
 <legend>Programs</legend>
 <p class="twoColumn" id="progList"></p>
</fieldset>
<p id="submit"><input type="submit" name="btnSubmit" value="Submit" /></p>
</form>
```

Comment: Why the novalidate? You could use the [required](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-required) attribute and simply remove the js validation

Comment: And for the age input, you can set a`min` and `max` attribute like so `<input type="number" name="age" min="0" max="80">`

Comment: Hey. It would be really good if you would try to make this into several separate questions, I think. The question is very broad, and Stack Overflow is intended for more specific questions. For instance, one question could be: How can i make validation happen after each field input? And  another: How can i make sure i validate an input as a number in range (0-80). I am sure that many of these questions are alredy answered here, and if some are not, just ask ;)

Comment: even if you use the novalidate you can still use the validation api `input.validity.valid`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, the question is very broad, please review: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and adjust your post accordingly.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So, the issue is, you're checking every value but never breaking out.  The simplest way is by throwing a return at the end of each of your catch blocks - that way if there IS an error, the function will stop executing instead of moving on and doing the very next check.

```
catch(msg) {
  errMsgDiv.style.display = "block";
  errMsgDiv.innerHTML = msg;
  formValidity = false;
  return;
}
```

Comment: This was the answer! Thanks Sergio. I swear I tried this but I think I might have had an error and thought it was due to the return;